# How does this default argument to a bash script work?

Tags: bash

I just discovered

```
default="no parameter provided"
echo ${1:-$default}  # in a script
```

What is this called? Is it a builtin? Does it work like it looks it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and is built-in to [any POSIX shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

> `${parameter:-word}`
>
> If *parameter* is unset or null, the expansion of *word* is substituted. Otherwise, the value of *parameter* is substituted.

In your example, if `${1}` is not unset or null, its value is output, otherwise the value of `${default}` is output instead.

Answer (score 3):

It's `Parameter Expansion`, described in in [Bash manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) that you can also invoke locally with `man bash`:

```
   ${parameter:-word}
          Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the
          expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value
          of parameter is substituted.
```